# I want to find the closest path to the polyline

Tags: java, android-studio, google-polyline

I need your knowledge to make my application, thanks in advance. Well, I'm using **Android Studio - Java** - Using the **Google maps API**, I generated several **polylines** on the map, I also added my current position, what I need is to **generate a route that will take me to the nearest polyline** and referring to the first image, I have a polyline with a certain number of coordinates represented by the red dots. The light blue dot would be my current position. What I need is to find the closest path to the polyline **without needing it to be one of the coordinates**

(PS: I don't speak English if you can explain me in the simplest way possible)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8z6C.png)

Aqui otros ejemplos

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcbDy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzzJ1.png)

I found some examples but they all seek to

> find the closest coordinate of the red points but the truth is that I
> want the closest point to the polyline

, it is a challenge for me so I am looking for help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpPin.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have modified my question, I hope now you understand what I need